# Stoichiometry of alkane-perchlorate reaction

Tags: stoichiometry

> What are the products of an alkane and a perchlorate reaction?
>
> e.g., making the alkane methane and the perchlorate anhydrous for simplicity:

**My effort**:

$$\ce{Mg(ClO4)2 + 4CH4 -> MgCl2 + 4CO2}$$

leaves 16H free so obviously incorrect, but shouldn't a salt and a gas be part of the products? I guess that the anhydrous form would make this explosive.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is some $\ce{H2O}$ as product:
$$\ce{2Mg(ClO4)2 + 4CH4 -> 2MgCl2 + 4CO2 + 8H2O}%edit$$